# How to create a variable with parameters just like \title or \author?

Tags: macros, renewcommand

Explaining what I want with Java:

```
String myTitle = "";

// Later on in the main method

myTitle = "";

System.out.println(myTitle);
```

I basically just want to create a new variable with newcommand, later on in the preamble give it a value just so I can output the variable after begin document.

```
\documentclass{scrartlc}

\newcommand{\myVariable}{}


\myVariable{FOOBAR}

\begin{document}

\myVariable

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\myVariable}{FOOBAR}`

Comment: `\title` and `\author` are not variables. They are macros for assigning values to internal "variables" `\@title`/`\@author`.  The command `\maketitle` causes LaTeX to create a nice title(page) for the document whereby LaTeX retrieves the values of the internal "variables" `\@title`/`\@author`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way is to use a command for assigning a meaning to some macro and then use that macro when needed.

You *might* do

```
\newcommand{\myVariable}[1]{\renewcommand{\myVariable}{#1}}
```

but this has several drawbacks:

1. you must know in advance what variables you're going to name and use;
2. you cannot change the value once set;
3. it's unnecessarily confusing setup and use.

Better do a general purpose variable defining command:

```
\newcommand{\defineVariable}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{#2}}
```

and use it like

```
\defineVariable{\myVariable}{FOOBAR}
```

However this doesn't allow for redefining. Using `\def#1{#2}` is really dangerous, because it would accept something like

```
\definevariable{\def}{FOOBAR}
```

and chaos would ensue for obvious reasons.

There's a slicker way that even frees you from the problem of spaces after `\myVariable`. Also the `user@variable@` prefix will protect from the risk of redefining important commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defineVariable}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname user@variable@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\useVariable}[1]{%
  \ifcsname user@variable@#1\endcsname
    \csname user@variable@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \@latex@error{Undefined variable '#1'}{The variable '#1' has never been defined}%
    ERRONEOUS VARIABLE%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\defineVariable{myVar}{FOOBAR}

\useVariable{myVar} is very useful.

\defineVariable{myVar}{something else}

\useVariable{myVar} is very useful.

\useVariable{undefined} is undefined

\end{document}
```

[image]

Console output:

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined variable 'undefined'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.27 \useVariable{undefined}
                             is undefined
? h
The variable 'undefined' has never been defined
?
```

An `expl3` implementation (without the error raising to preserve expandability, although this could be added).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineVariable}{mm}
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l__user_variables_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\useVariable}{m}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \l__user_variables_prop { #1 }
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \l__user_variables_prop { #1 }
   }
   {
    ERRONEOUS~VARIABLE
   }
 }

\prop_new:N \l__user_variables_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defineVariable{myVar}{FOOBAR}

\useVariable{myVar} is very useful.

\defineVariable{myVar}{something else}

\useVariable{myVar} is very useful.

\useVariable{undefined} is undefined

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `\myVariable` as token register

```
\newtoks\myVariable
```

then a user can set a value to it

```
\myVariable{FOOBAR}
```

and then a you can use this value in your macros

```
\the\myVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @wipet's answer very much (I did not know you could do that!), but I thought that I would post how I usually solve the same problem as yours, with
`\providecommand` to define the variable (and its default value), and `\renewcommand` to assign a new value to it (potentially multiple times):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\providecommand{\myVariable}{Default Value}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Default value is: ``\myVariable''
\item \renewcommand{\myVariable}{First Updated value}
First updated value is: ``\myVariable''
\item \renewcommand{\myVariable}{Second Updated value}
Second updated value is: ``\myVariable''
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the code above should give the following output:
[image: output of LaTeX code with a default value updated twice]

Hope it helps!